# inject/autowire datasource from spring when more than one datasource is specified

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to inject from my context.xml file a datasource. I have this config file but the issue is, i have more than one datasource at anytime. When i try to inject any of them, I get an error that says there is a no matching bean.
Here is my code.

```
    @Inject
    @Named("dataSourceAccounts")
    //@Autowired
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        System.out.println("jdbcTemplate is null? " + (jdbcTemplate == null));

    }

//for the context.xml
<context:component-scan base-package="business" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="middleware" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="presentation" /> 
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean id="txManagerProducts" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProducts"/>
    </bean >
    <bean id="txManagerAccounts" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceAccounts"/>
    </bean >

     <bean id="dataSourceProducts" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productsdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accountsdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
```

Thanks for your help in a advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the qualified name for the dependency that should be injected, the @Named should precede the param definition:

```
@Inject
@Override
public void setDataSource(@Named("dataSourceAccounts") DataSource dataSource) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    System.out.println("jdbcTemplate is null? " + (jdbcTemplate == null));

}
```

or using spring annotations:

```
@Autowired
@Override
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceAccounts") DataSource dataSource)
```

Comment: @Ayodeji may be because your data sources names in XML config are: "dataSourceProducts" and "dataSource" while you specified "dataSourceAccounts" to be injected.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Named(value=dataSourceAccounts)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
 I had to trim some of it

Comment: @Ayodeji which version of spring you are using?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I'm using 3 (3.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
@javax.annotation.Resource(name="dataSourceProducts")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
                 ...
}
```

javax.annotation.Resource is in Java SE

Comment: It shows another error saying "No bean named 'dataSourceProducts' is defined" even though i have it defined in the xml file